# Why can't Jars in Jars see the contents of other Jars in Jars if they are in the same Jar?

Tags: spring-boot, jar, classloader

**tl;dr:** The classes in our Spring Boot jar seem to see classes within the bundled jars, but their contents don't seem to be able to. Why?

---

Our main product is a web app, but all the business logic is centralized in a core `mac-guffin-api.jar`. `mac-guffin-api.jar` is *not* a Spring Boot project, but has a Spring Java config file called `net.initech.api.Configuration` that initializes all the services and repositories etc. We use MS SQL Server as our backend with the `sqljdbc42:jar` driver.

We needed to write an ETL that needed to reuse the same business logic from API project so we created a Spring Boot Spring Batch project that imports `mac-guffin-api.jar` as a Maven dependency. The ETL's configuration (`net.initech.etl.Configuration`)import's APIs configuration without problem (I can see it from the console logging) but when the API configuration goes to create the database connection **it cannot find the driver.**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 113 more
```

However, I can clearly see that the JAR containing the driver is present. The contents of the ETL jar are (**Nb:** `mac-guffin-api.jar` and `sqljdbc42-4.2.jar` are *not* unpacked, they are jars in the ETL jar ) :

```
mac-guffin-etl.jar
|
+- org.springframework.boot.loader...
|
+- BOOT-INF
   |
   +- classes
   |  |
   |  +- com.initech.etl.Main.class
   |  |
   |  +- com.initech.etl.Configuration.class
   |
   +- lib
      |
      +- mac-guffin-api.jar
      |  |
      |  +- com.initech.api.Configuration.class
      |
      +- sqljdbc42-4.2.jar
         |
         +- com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class
```

So apparently the class ETL's configuration class can see the content's of the included JARs (or at least the contents of API jar), but they API jar does not seem to be able to see the `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class` in the fellow SQL Server JDBC jar.

I'm even able to do a `Class.forName( "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class" )` from before the instantiation of the Spring context and it doesn't have a problem.

Is this is a limitation of the class loader? Is this because the API project is not Spring Boot? Is it because of a missing configuration parameter? What is going on here?

Comment: Interesting issue... could be a few things.  Any way for you to share a very minimal, reproducible project on GitHub? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I dont remember properly but does a classname always appear in quotes In a classnotfoundexcepetion? single quotes also seems a bit non-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your configuration, you have ended up with the classname that is being used as the value:

```
'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
```

with single quotes around it. Normally the class name being loaded is printed without quotes, double or single.

This would explain why you are able to load the class but the API jar is not. Check you configuration/build files for where the driver name is set.

### DEMO

The only way I can get a message like yours:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
```

and not:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Is to deliberately ask to load a class with single quotes in the name. For example:

```java
import java.lang.*;

public class myclass {

        public static void test(String thename) {
                System.out.println("trying " + thename);
                try {
                        myclass test = (myclass) myclass.class
                                .getClassLoader()
                                .loadClass(thename)
                                .newInstance();
                        System.out.println(test.toString());
                } catch (Exception e){
                        System.out.println("failed to load " + thename);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                test("my.package.itwontexist");
                test("'my.package.itwontexist'");
        }
}
```

outputs:

```
trying my.package.itwontexist
failed to load my.package.itwontexist
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.itwontexist
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at myclass.test(myclass.java:10)
    at myclass.main(myclass.java:20)
trying 'my.package.itwontexist'
failed to load 'my.package.itwontexist'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 'my.package.itwontexist'
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at myclass.test(myclass.java:10)
    at myclass.main(myclass.java:21)
```

Answer (score 2):

Its possible that you are getting driver value from configuration, e.g.

> my.driver = 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'

And that configuration is returning value with single quotes. Please check your configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the MANFIEST.MF file that directs Spring on how to load the nested jars.  Here's an example hierarchy from Spring's documentation.  You can read up on how to configure it [by going here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html).

The MANIFEST.MF should contain this (for the structure below):

```
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.mycompany.project.MyApplication
```

`Start-Class` is your entry point into your application
`Main-Class` is the Loader you need to load the nested jars.

Example structure:

```
example.war
 |
 +-META-INF
 |  +-MANIFEST.MF
 +-org
 |  +-springframework
 |     +-boot
 |        +-loader
 |           +-<spring boot loader classes>
 +-WEB-INF
    +-classes
    |  +-com
    |     +-mycompany
    |        +-project
    |           +-YourClasses.class
    +-lib
    |  +-dependency1.jar
    |  +-dependency2.jar
    +-lib-provided
       +-servlet-api.jar
       +-dependency3.jar
```